# Adding two String to a jtable while adding there sum into a jTextField

Tags: java, string, netbeans, jtable, sum

I'm trying to build a GUI with NetBeans, I've put into the MainFrame which is the first JFrame of my program a JTextField (jTextFieldT) and a JTable (jTable2), and now in the second frame named AdderFrame I've put JTextField (jTextField2) and a button when I click the button the Price is added to a row into the Table. Now i'm trying to put the price into the jTextFieldT and every time i update the table using the AdderFrame i want the price that i put to be added to the price that already have been put into the jTextFieldT.

Now my main problem is that I can't use an int to add to the jtable, but it seems that I can't find any way to put 2 strings that will be added to the table into the jtextFieldT and make there sum.

This is the code that i'm using on the button of the AdderFrame:

```
String Brand;
String Item;
String Price;
String Date;
String Dept;
String Total;

Brand = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
Item  =jTextField1.getText().toString();  
Date  =jTextField4.getText().toString();
Dept  =jCheckBox1.getText().toString();
Price=jTextField2.getText().toString();
Total=MainFrame.jTextFieldT.getText().toString();

MainFrame.jTextFieldT.setText(+(Total+Price));

DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)MainFrame.jTable2.getModel();
if(jCheckBox1.isSelected()){
   model.addRow(new Object[]{Brand,Item,Price,Date,true});
}  else {
   model.addRow(new Object[]{Brand,Item,Price,Date});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No need to call `toString()` on text obtained from a text component. It's automatically a String.
2. If you need to convert a String to an int, use `Integer.parseInt(stringToConvert)`.
3. You should usually do this within a try/catch block to catch any NumberFormatExceptions that might occur if you try to parse a String that's not a valid int representation.
4. Once the Strings are converted, adding them is trivial.
5. You can also add your ints to the row Object array by converting them to Integer wrapper objects.
6. You appear to be trying to directly access fields of another object, suggesting that these fields are public. Make them private and don't directly access them.
7. Learn and follow Java naming conventions. Method and variable names should begin with lower-case letters and class names with upper case letters.
8. You really don't want your program to display multiple JFrames at the same time or even sequentially, believe me. Usually it is better to either show a dialog as a dialog window such as a modal JDialog or to swap views via CardLayout.